# JS script not running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have no experience with JS or JQuery.

I'm trying to use this: http://codepen.io/highplainsdrifter/pen/Aicls

The clock renders but does not actually work. For the JavaScript, I tried pasting it in between `<script></script>` tags in the html, and also tried putting it into it's own file and referring to it `<script src="./clock.js"></script>`

**Is something missing from this, some semicolon or punctuation?**

```
var clockH = $(".hours");
var clockM = $(".minutes");
var clockS = $(".seconds");

function time() {     
  var d = new Date(),
      s = d.getSeconds() * 6,
      m = d.getMinutes() * 6,
      h = d.getHours() % 12 / 12 * 360;  
    clockH.css("transform", "rotate("+h+"deg)");
    clockM.css("transform", "rotate("+m+"deg)"); 
    clockS.css("transform", "rotate("+s+"deg)");    
}
var clock = setInterval(time, 1000);
```

=========

Updates. Ok, so here is what I have in my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var clockH = $(".hours");
var clockM = $(".minutes");
var clockS = $(".seconds");

function time() {     
  var d = new Date(),
      s = d.getSeconds() * 6,
      m = d.getMinutes() * 6,
      h = d.getHours() % 12 / 12 * 360;  
    clockH.css("transform", "rotate("+h+"deg)");
    clockM.css("transform", "rotate("+m+"deg)"); 
    clockS.css("transform", "rotate("+s+"deg)");    
}
var clock = setInterval(time, 1000);

});
```

In the HTML:

```
<script src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./clock.js"></script>
```

and

```
<div class="clock">
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <span class="midday"></span>
    <span class="three"></span>
    <span class="six"></span>
    <span class="nine"></span>
</div>
```

Finally, in my css:

```
body { background: #574b57; }

.clock {
    background-color:#c7c7c7;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 4px solid #999;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
      box-shadow: 1px 5px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.clock:after {
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:#FFF 5px solid;
    content:"";
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.1);
      box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.1);

}
.clock span {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;

}
.clock .hours {
    height: 30%;
    width: 5px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.2);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.2);
      box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.2);

}
.clock .minutes {
    height: 45%;
    width: 3px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.2);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.2);
      box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.2);
}
.clock .seconds {
    background: #949494;
    height: 47%;
    width: 1px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
      box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
}
.clock .midday, .clock .three, .clock .six, .clock .nine {
    background: #949494;
    height: 10%;
    width: 6px;
    left: 49%;
    top: 2%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.3);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.3);
      box-shadow: 1px 0px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
.clock .three {
    top: 49%;
    left: 89%;
    height: 6px;
    width: 10%;
}
.clock .six {
    top: 89%;
    left: 49%;
}
.clock .nine {
    top: 49%;
    left: 1%;
    height: 6px;
    width: 10%;
}
```

**But for some reason this is how the clock looks, any ideas on why so?**

[image]

Comment: The codepen code you posted works in my computer. Does it not for you ?

Comment: You can debug it in your browser. In Chrome or Firefox (with Firebug), usually pressing F12 will bring up the dev tools. Place breakpoints in your code, and watch the console for exceptions.

Comment: Can you post the whole code? I suspect you are missing some important library?

Comment: Are you using the exact HTML, CSS and JS from the codepen site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using jQuery wrap your function in document.ready like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var clockH = $(".hours");
var clockM = $(".minutes");
var clockS = $(".seconds");

function time() {     
  var d = new Date(),
  s = d.getSeconds() * 6,
  m = d.getMinutes() * 6,
  h = d.getHours() % 12 / 12 * 360;  
clockH.css("transform", "rotate("+h+"deg)");
clockM.css("transform", "rotate("+m+"deg)"); 
clockS.css("transform", "rotate("+s+"deg)");    
}
var clock = setInterval(time, 1000);

});
```

Also make sure you are referencing jQuery in your script tags.

Comment: Yup, just wasn't wrapped in that jQuery thingy, thanks! Now I just have to figure out why it's all slanted.

Comment: Good to know that fixed it! When using jQuery, it's nearly always mandatory that you use the above method for things to run smoothly. Could you provide a screenshot of the slanted clock?

Comment: I can't say the exact issues but it looks like because the clock's css is using percentages and not absolute measurements (like pixels), the size of the container it is in will matter. Basically you need to place your clock HTML into a container the same size as the one on codepen

Comment: I'm sorry, I just cant seem to get it right, what is the outer container supposed to look like for its properties, I tried 250 by 250 , that does not seem to work.

Comment: shouldnt you use the shorthand $(function() instead of $(document).ready(function() ?

Answer (score 2):

The script requires jQuery. The variables with $ are trying to create jQuery objects from the selector that is passed as a parameter.

Place another script tag above the clock script, with the following content:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

It is also good practice to wrap any code that requires jQuery in a document.ready closure.
i.e.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Clock script here
});
```